# When I use my key to connect to my AMI CentOS 6.3 server as ec2-user, it still asks for a password. Why?

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2

The command I'm using is:

```
ssh -i /<path-to-your-key>/<your-key>.pem ec2-user@ec2-<your-domain>.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Why would it STILL ask for a password when i have the key? It has you specify a key when you launch the instance; so if I use the key when I connect, it shouldn't ask for a password. I have no idea what it is because you're supposed to use the key to connect, right? What step have I overlooked?

Comment: Can you actually login or not? Is it asking for a password or a passphrase? What does `ssh -v -i ...` output?

Answer (score 1):

The username that you log into the instance with depends on the AMI. The user `ec2-user` may not be correct. You will want to check the specifications for the particular AMI that you used to create the instance that you are connecting to.

Comment: YES! SunSparc thank you for the answer, precisely what the issue was! Since it was AWS I assumed you used ec2-user. Apparently root is the proper login. TY!

Comment: You are very welcome. I usually use Ubuntu AMI's and oftentimes the username is "ubuntu", but not always. I am glad I could help. Feel free to click the checkmark. :)